# how to specify TLS version in cloudformation template for REST API?

Tags: rest, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

Creating a stack, REST API - with API gateway and other resources. where can I specify if the API methods support just HTTP or HTTPS, or any specific version of TLS in the template?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: API Gateway

Parameters:
  apiGatewayHTTPMethod:
    Type: String
    Default: POST

Resources:
  apiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL
      Name: fooAPI
  apiGatewayRootMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: !Ref apiGatewayHTTPMethod
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt lambdaFunction.Arn
      ResourceId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway

  apiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn:
      - apiGatewayRootMethod
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      StageName: BETA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. REST API is **only HTTPS**, and you can't change it to HTTP.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to view/edit the TLS version in API gateway. I can't see where it shows default TLS version in the api gateway. I looked under resources, stages ... but can't find it. is there a place to see that information under api gateway

Comment: @ozil I think you can only do this for a [custom domain in the api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html).

Comment: so without the custom domain , is there a default TLS version that is set?